# Imagens lado a lado alinhadas em qualquer tela

Tags: html5, imagem, grid

### HTML

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="imgs/Logo Aguia vet.png" alt="Logo Aguia Informatica" class="responsive"></a>
<a href="http://mactronengenharia.com.br/" target="_blank"><img src="imgs/mactron engenharia.png" alt="Logo Mactron Engenharia" class="responsive"></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="imgs/aldosolar.png" alt="Aldo Solar" class="responsive"> </a>
```

### CSS

```css
.responsive { /*Logos rodapé*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 9em;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Olá. seria interessante se você passasse naus detalhes sobre a situação e mais código

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está quase certo, o problema é a forma como vc usou a classe e alguma propriedades que são desnecessárias...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vc colocou a classe direto na imagem, mas o mais adequado ao meu ver seria criar um *container* e colocar a classe nesse *conteiner*.

```css
.responsive { /*Logos rodapé*/
  display: inline-block;
  /* margin-left: 9em; */
  /* margin-right: auto; */
  width: 100%;
  /* max-width: 250px; */
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="Logo Aguia Informatica" ></a>
  <a href="http://mactronengenharia.com.br/" target="_blank"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="Logo Mactron Engenharia" ></a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="Aldo Solar" > </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Vlw funcionou legal.

Comment: @CaioCésarRubo legal que deu certo, se vc acha que resolveu o problema considere marcar a resposta como aceita nesse ícone ao lado das setinhas `✔`. Assim sua pergunta não fica sem resposta aceita mesmo já tendo sido resolvida.

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisa de imagens lado a lado, você pode utilizar o `display: flex` com as propriedades, `justify-content: center;` e `align-items:center;` que eles irão alinhar todo o conteúdo de sua div lado a lado.
O `display: flex` já vem como padrão `flex-direction: row`, caso você precise que as imagens fiquem uma abaixo da outra, você só precisa mudar para `flex-direction: column`.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

img {
margin: 2.5px;
height: 5em;
width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/711520911082569728/CZvvAEVD.jpg">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/711520911082569728/CZvvAEVD.jpg">

  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/711520911082569728/CZvvAEVD.jpg">

</div>
```

Comment: Usando flex realmente endereça o "alinhadas em qualquer tela", vale notar também, se houver necessidade de suporte ao IE9 (até mesmo o 10 e 11 devido a muitos bugs), use a solução de @hugocsl

Comment: Usando o visual studio o flex não funcionou, a sugestão acima resolveu meu problema.